# WCF - unable to stop net.tcp binding (hosted on IIS)

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, tcp

I have working WCF service on IIS with configured net.tcp endpoint. After disable page on IIS I'm still able to run request to my service **o.O**.
Disabling application pool works as expected (service is no longer available).

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="xyz.Service.Authentication.Implementation.AuthenticationService">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding"
                  contract="xyz.Service.Authentication.Model.IAuthenticationService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding" sendTimeout="00:00:30" 
                 transactionFlow="false" 
                 portSharingEnabled="false"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="18000">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="Sign"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseWindowsGroups"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Is it a bug or a feature  ?

Comment: I'd call it a feature.  IIS is hosting your service, so when IIS receives the request it passes it off to the service (or starts it if its not running).  Why do you think this is a bug?

Comment: Because I stopped IIS page/applicationso and endpoints configured to use http bindings are not responding (not in posted web.config). If it's a feature then it's very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem and I found out that:

- Stopping Web Site does **not** stop the net.tcp service
- Disable App Pool disables service but does **not** free the port, port is still used by **SMSvcHost.exe**
- Restarting after does not helps too.

The only way to free port ( to be used by something else ) was to **delete net.tcp binding** in IIS.

I spent time on this, because received wrong answers from net.tcp service. It took me while, to find out - it's not from my service, but from old disabled one. This could save time to someone else.

[image: Delete net.tcp binding]